# Why isn't this jquery event handler wiring up as expected?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a radio button list with a name of "ReportTypeId". For each `radio` button I want to display an alert with its value when it's clicked.

I wrote the following jQuery which gets all 5 radio buttons the list with a name of "ReportTypeId":

```
$("[name='ReportTypeId']").toArray().forEach(function(reportTypeId){
    reportTypeId.click(function(reportTypeId){
       alert(reportTypeId.value);
    });
});
```

When I set a breakpoint and examine tthe variables at load time the variables look as expected.  However, when I click on a radio button after page load nothing happens.  What I am doing wrong in the jquery above?

Comment: Is your code in `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: BTW, instead of `.toArray().forEach()`, you can just use jQuery's built-in `.each()`.

Comment: `reportTypeId` is a DOM element, not a jQuery object. You need `$(reportTypeId).click`.

Comment: You should be getting an error saying that it has no `.click()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `this` to get the current element inside of your callback function to `.click()`. The argument passed to function is actually the click event object.

```
$("[name='ReportTypeId']").toArray().forEach(function(reportTypeId){
    reportTypeId.click(function(event){
        alert(this.value);
    });
});
```

---

You can simplify your code a lot simply by calling `.click()` on the jQuery collection. The event listener will automatically be attached to all the elements in the collection.

```
$("[name='ReportTypeId']").click(function(event){
    alert(this.value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could attach click event to all buttons in same time because they have the same name `ReportTypeId`, you don't need to use `.forEach()` and loop... then to get the value use `.val()` :

```
$("body").on('click', '[name='ReportTypeId']', function(){
     alert($(this).val());
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$("body").on('click', '[name="ReportTypeId"]', function(){
     alert($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='radio' name='ReportTypeId' value='radio_1' checked/> Radio 1
<br>
<input type='radio' name='ReportTypeId' value='radio_2'/> Radio 2
<br>
<input type='radio' name='ReportTypeId' value='radio_3'/> Radio 3
<br>
<input type='radio' name='ReportTypeId' value='radio_4'/> Radio 4
```

Comment: Why is it bad practice to use anonymous function inside loops? `.each()` is not a loop.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki That problem is with `for` loops, not `.forEach()` loops.

Comment: But you don't have problems with closure variables like you do if you use a `for` loop. Each iteration has its own variable environment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("[name='ReportTypeId']").click(function(){
    alert(this.value);
});
```

use this inside of function callback and you don't have to use toArray()

Answer (score 0):

`reportTypeId.value` is probably undefined and therefore, no alert will be displayed.

It is undefined because by default the first argument in the click event callback function is the `event` object, not the radio button itself. Try alerting `this.value` instead of `reportTypeId.value`.